# Maven: Result of Antrun is in target, but not in output of site-stage and site-deploy. Why?

Tags: maven-2, report, maven-antrun-plugin

I have configured the ant-run-plugin to run in the post-site phase. By the way, it transforms to findbugs-report. I find its result in my target/site-folder. Calling site-stage produces the entire multi-module site in an extra directory. There, my transformed findbugs-report is missing. Why is that?

I assumend stage-site copies the pieces from every target/site to my stating directory. It does not do that. It seems to recreate everything, but overlooks my transformed report. How can I tell it to pick it up?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you've almost answered this question yourself. About the [site:stage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/stage-mojo.html) goal, the documentation writes:

> Generates a site in a local staging or mock directory based on the site URL specified in the `<distributionManagement>` section of the POM.
>
> It can be used to test that links between module sites in a multi module build works.

So, no, site:stage doesn't copy files generated by site:site, it generates "another" site.

Thus, processing `target/site` when running the antrun plugin  is fine when you run [site:site](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/site-mojo.html), but not when you run [site:stage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/stage-mojo.html). When running [site:stage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/stage-mojo.html), you need to tell it to process the staging directory.